# Dataset with Datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I am trying to check if my dictionary contains values in my dataset.datatable and if its quantities in the second column of the dataset are less than or greater than the quantities in my datatable. I tried using the SELECT method but it doesn’t seem to work, I get the error BC30469 reference to non-shared member requires object reference?
I was just trying to do a simple search in the table first to see if I can even do that..... apparently not. Thanks for the help!

```
 Dim row As DataRow = DataSet.DataTable.Select("ColumnName1 = 'value3'")
    If Not row Is Nothing Then
        searchedValue = row.Item("ColumnName2")
    End If
```

Comment: A DataSet has no Columns :) Maybe something like: `Dim row = [SomeDataSetInstance].Tables("Some DataTable").Select("ColumnName1 = 'value3'").SingleOrDefault() If row IsNot Nothing Then [...]`

Comment: `BC30469 reference to non-shared member requires object reference?` is always if you do something on the class instead of your object. If you write `Object.ToString()` you get that error, if you call `.ToString()` on an object it works.

Comment: Is this a typed DataSet or an untyped DataSet? Did you generate it with the wizard at design time or create it in code at run time?

Comment: The dataset is uploaded, it contains standard quantities and name, it should never be entered...... unfortunately nothing helped my issue

Answer (score 1):

You could get a dictionary to compare with the one you already have like this (assuming your key is a string and the amount an Int32 and that your dataset contains only one table):

```
Dim myDBDict As Dictionary(Of String, Int32) =
    From e In myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).ToDictionary(Of String, Int32)(
        Function(e) e.Field(Of String)("MyIDColumn"),
        Function(e) e.Field(Of Int32)("myAmountColumn"))
```

Comment: is this not C#? Im not sure what the equivalent of this would be in VB.net

Comment: @lerne8423: No, that's pure VB.NET.